# Is there a way to stop a running process in concurrent.futures?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

How can I terminate a running process, started using [concurrent.futures](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/concurrent.futures.html)? As I understand, the `cancel()` method is there to remove a process from the queue if it is not running. But what about killing a running process? For example, if I have a long running process, and I want to stop it when I press a Cancel button in a GUI.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it would probably be better to use a `multiprocessing.Process` for a long running task.

Create a `multiprocessing.Event` *before* starting the new process. Have the child process check the status of this `Event` regularly, and make it exit when `Event.is_set()` returns `True`.

In your GUI code, have the callback associated with the button call `set()` on the `Event`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at my answer to a related StackOverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45515052/2063031).

In short, there does not appear to be a simple way to cancel a running process inside a `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`. But you can accomplish it in a *hacky* way by killing the child processes manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `_processes` from the executor.

For example `script.py`:

```py
import signal
import time
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor


def sleep_squre(x):
    def sigterm_handler(signum, frame):
        raise SystemExit(signum)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, sigterm_handler)
    try:
        time.sleep(x)
    except SystemExit:
        return -1
    return x * x

with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as ex:
    results = ex.map(sleep_squre, [1, 5])
    time.sleep(3)
    for pid, proc in ex._processes.items():
        proc.terminate()
print(list(results))
```

In this case, we send SIGKILL after 3 seconds to all processes.

```bash
$ python3 script.py
[1, -1]
```