# Python: concurrent.futures How to make it cancelable?

Tags: python, multiprocess, concurrent.futures

Python concurrent.futures and ProcessPoolExecutor provide a neat interface to schedule and monitor tasks. Futures even [provide](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) a .cancel() method:

> **cancel()**:    Attempt to cancel the call. If the call is **currently being executed and cannot be cancelled** then the method will return False, otherwise the call will be cancelled and the method will return True.

Unfortunately in a simmilar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26413613/asyncio-is-it-possible-to-cancel-a-future-been-run-by-an-executor) (concerning asyncio) the answer claims running tasks are uncancelable using this snipped of the documentation, but the docs dont say that, only if they are running AND uncancelable.

Submitting multiprocessing.Events to the processes is also not trivially possible (doing so via parameters as in multiprocess.Process returns a RuntimeError)

What am I trying to do? I would like to partition a search space and run a task for every partition. But it is enough to have ONE solution and the process is CPU intensive. So is there an actual comfortable way to accomplish this that does not offset the gains by using ProcessPool to begin with?

Example:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, FIRST_COMPLETED, wait

# function that profits from partitioned search space
def m_run(partition):
    for elem in partition:
        if elem == 135135515:
            return elem
    return False

futures = []
# used to create the partitions
steps = 100000000
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as pool:
    for i in range(4):
        # run 4 tasks with a partition, but only *one* solution is needed
        partition = range(i*steps,(i+1)*steps)
        futures.append(pool.submit(m_run, partition))

    done, not_done = wait(futures, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)
    for d in done:
        print(d.result())

    print("---")
    for d in not_done:
        # will return false for Cancel and Result for all futures
        print("Cancel: "+str(d.cancel()))
        print("Result: "+str(d.result()))
```

Comment: You can try to set the `Event` to global variable instead of passing it as a param, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675766/how-to-combine-pool-map-with-array-shared-memory-in-python-multiprocessing

Comment: @niemmi thank you for the tipp. I'll probably try this as a workaround, as it doesnt feel well designed with calls to different modules.

Comment: Maybe this is all linked to the fact that there is no immediate cancel POSIX API either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084830/kill-thread-in-pthread-library

Answer (score 18):

Unfortunately, running `Futures` cannot be cancelled. I believe the core reason is to ensure the same API over different implementations (it's not possible to interrupt running threads or coroutines).

The [Pebble](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pebble) library was designed to overcome this and other limitations.

```
from pebble import ProcessPool

def function(foo, bar=0):
    return foo + bar

with ProcessPool() as pool:
    future = pool.schedule(function, args=[1])

    # if running, the container process will be terminated 
    # a new process will be started consuming the next task
    future.cancel()
```

Comment: I found it handy to know that the `pebble` futures inherit from the `concurrent.futures` futures. Therefore, many methods provided by `concurrent.futures` can also be applied to the `pebble` futures even if `pebble` does not implement these methods. This applies e.g. for the `as_completed` method of `concurrent.futures`. As a result, switching to pebble may be as easy as adding an import and changing the names of the `ProcessPoolExecuter` and `pool.submit`.

Comment: This may be obvious, but I just wanted to note that if you are using a ProcessPool you're no longer using multiple threads, but rather multiple processes. Many people will not care about the distinction but it's worth at least knowing what you're doing.

Comment: OP uses `ProcessPoolExecutor` so it's fair to use `ProcessPool`. `pebble` also has `ThreadPool` if you want to replace `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: @fireattack If I read the docs right, threads cannot be interrupted with pebble either. Threadpool.stop(): "The ongoing jobs will be performed. [...]". https://pebble.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#pebble.ThreadPool.stop

Comment: @Joooeey you don't use that, you use future.cancel().

While it's just a standard concurrent.futures.Future object, from my first hand experience, it works flawlessly (for stopping child threads immediately.) when you're using pebble.

Comment: @fireattack are you sure this works when threading as opposed to multiprocessing? According to the pebble docs for `.cancel()` it doesn’t kill a running thread.

Comment: A Python thread can only exit by its own, it cannot be terminated by another thread. Hence, only `ProcessPool` can stop a running execution. `ThreadPool` futures `cancel` function will act exactly as `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: @Joooeey @noxdafox there is absolutely a difference, it's very easy to try it yourself. I made a quick script: https://gist.github.com/fireattack/ab00953be7e31e8cfa72d18ca695c1ef try to `time python a.py pebble` and `time python a.py concurrent` and see the difference. I honestly don't know how they accomplish it, but it's real.

Comment: @fireattack This approach only makes it possible for Python to quit while threads are still running but it doesn't cancel threads. Add `sleep(10)` to the end of your script and print lines to your `slow` function to see for yourself.

Comment: @Joooeey: could you elaborate? Why does it work with pebble but not built-in concurrent.futures's ThreadPoolExecutor?

Comment: What works with a pebble ThreadPool but not with a standard library ThreadPoolExecutor? In any case I don't think I know enough to explain why. I can only observe what does and does not work.

Comment: @Joooeey Using pebble I'm able to terminate python process before children threads finishes, With standard lib I can't. This is often needed in certain scenarios to be able to force stop the work immediately.

Comment: Exactly, when you terminate the Python process, you can terminate running threads when using pebble. But you can't terminate running threads without shutting down the Python process.

Comment: @Joooeey the question is why you can't do so with `concurrent.futures`.

Answer (score 15):

I don't know why `concurrent.futures.Future` does not have a `.kill()` method, but you can accomplish what you want by shutting down the process pool with `pool.shutdown(wait=False)`, and killing the remaining child processes by hand.

Create a function for killing child processes:

```
import signal, psutil

def kill_child_processes(parent_pid, sig=signal.SIGTERM):
    try:
        parent = psutil.Process(parent_pid)
    except psutil.NoSuchProcess:
        return
    children = parent.children(recursive=True)
    for process in children:
        process.send_signal(sig)
```

Run your code until you get the first result, then kill all remaining child processes:

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, FIRST_COMPLETED, wait

# function that profits from partitioned search space
def m_run(partition):
    for elem in partition:
        if elem == 135135515:
            return elem
    return False

futures = []
# used to create the partitions
steps = 100000000
pool = ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)
for i in range(4):
    # run 4 tasks with a partition, but only *one* solution is needed
    partition = range(i*steps,(i+1)*steps)
    futures.append(pool.submit(m_run, partition))

done, not_done = wait(futures, timeout=3600, return_when=FIRST_COMPLETED)

# Shut down pool
pool.shutdown(wait=False)

# Kill remaining child processes
kill_child_processes(os.getpid())
```

Answer (score 1):

I found your question interesting so here's my finding.

I found the behaviour of `.cancel()` method is as stated in python documentation. As for your running concurrent functions, unfortunately they could not be cancelled even after they were told to do so. If my finding is correct, then I reason that Python does require a more effective .cancel() method.

Run the code below to check my finding.

```
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from time import time 

# function that profits from partitioned search space
def m_run(partition):
    for elem in partition:
        if elem == 3351355150:
            return elem
            break #Added to terminate loop once found
    return False

start = time()
futures = []
# used to create the partitions
steps = 1000000000
with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as pool:
    for i in range(4):
        # run 4 tasks with a partition, but only *one* solution is needed
        partition = range(i*steps,(i+1)*steps)
        futures.append(pool.submit(m_run, partition))

    ### New Code: Start ### 
    for f in as_completed(futures):
        print(f.result())
        if f.result():
            print('break')
            break

    for f in futures:
        print(f, 'running?',f.running())
        if f.running():
            f.cancel()
            print('Cancelled? ',f.cancelled())

    print('New Instruction Ended at = ', time()-start )
print('Total Compute Time = ', time()-start )
```

**Update:**
It is possible to forcefully terminate the concurrent processes via bash, but the consequence is that the main python program will terminate too. If this isn't an issue with you, then try the below code.

You have to add the below codes between the last 2 print statements to see this for yourself. Note: This code works only if you aren't running any other python3 program.

```
import subprocess, os, signal 
result = subprocess.run(['ps', '-C', 'python3', '-o', 'pid='],
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8').split()
print ('result =', result)
for i in result:
    print('PID = ', i)
    if i != result[0]:
        os.kill(int(i), signal.SIGKILL)
        try: 
           os.kill(int(i), 0)
           raise Exception("""wasn't able to kill the process 
                              HINT:use signal.SIGKILL or signal.SIGABORT""")
        except OSError as ex:
           continue
```

Answer (score 0):

For one of my software, I needed to kill all running processes of my executor when calling the `.shutdown()` method. As it was not possible with the standard `ProcessPoolExecutor`, I done it myself. I also fixed the wrong running state reported by future objects:

```py
import sys
import functools
import multiprocessing
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from concurrent.futures._base import RUNNING


def _callable_wrapper(is_running, fn, *args, **kwargs):
    is_running.value = True
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
    is_running.value = False


def _future_running_override(future, is_running):
    return future._state == RUNNING and is_running.value


class StoppableProcessPoolExecutor(ProcessPoolExecutor):
    """A concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor that kills running processes on
    shutdown.
    This also fix the wrong running state of futures. See
    https://bugs.python.org/issue37276
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._state_manager = multiprocessing.Manager()
        ProcessPoolExecutor.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    def shutdown(self, *args, **kwargs):
        processes = self._processes

        # Python < 3.9: We should wait else we got an OSError:
        # https://bugs.python.org/issue36281
        if sys.version_info.major >= 3 and sys.version_info.minor < 9:
            kwargs["wait"] = True

        for pid, process in processes.items():
            process.kill()
        ProcessPoolExecutor.shutdown(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._state_manager.shutdown()

    shutdown.__doc__ = ProcessPoolExecutor.shutdown.__doc__

    def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
        is_running = self._state_manager.Value(bool, False)
        future = ProcessPoolExecutor.submit(
            self,
            functools.partial(_callable_wrapper, is_running, fn),
            *args,
            **kwargs,
        )
        # Monkey patch future.running to return the real running state
        future.running = functools.partial(_future_running_override, future, is_running)
        return future

    submit.__doc__ = ProcessPoolExecutor.submit.__doc__
```

Original source: https://github.com/flozz/yoga-image-optimizer/blob/master/yoga_image_optimizer/stoppable_process_pool_executor.py

If it can help someone... :)