# How to catch exceptions thrown by functions executed using multiprocessing.Process() (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, multiprocessing

How can I catch exceptions from a process that was executed using [`multiprocessing.Process()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process)?

Consider the following python script that executes a simple `failFunction()` (which immediately throws a runtime error) inside of a child process using `mulitprocessing.Process()`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import multiprocessing, time

# this function will be executed in a child process asynchronously
def failFunction():
   raise RuntimeError('trust fall, catch me!')

# execute the helloWorld() function in a child process in the background
process = multiprocessing.Process(
 target = failFunction,
)
process.start()

# <this is where async stuff would happen>
time.sleep(1)

# try (and fail) to catch the exception
try:
    process.join()
except Exception as e:
    print( "This won't catch the exception" )
```

As you can see from the following execution, attempting to wrap the `.join()` does **not** actually catch the exception

```
user@host:~$ python3 example.py 
Process Process-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 297, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 99, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "example4.py", line 6, in failFunction
    raise RuntimeError('trust fall, catch me!')
RuntimeError: trust fall, catch me!
user@host:~$
```

How can I update the above script to actually catch the exception from the function that was executed inside of a child process using `multiprocessing.Process()`?

Comment: I believe you'd have to communicate the processes yourself in such case, as once you do the `fork`, child process lives on its own - I don't believe that such "exception propagation" would be possible on OS level. Here's a very reasonable approach using Queue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19929767/5430833

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be achieved by overloading the `run()` method in the `multiprocessing.Proccess()` class with a `try..except` statement and setting up a `Pipe()` to get and store any raised exceptions from the child process into an instance field for named `exception`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import multiprocessing, traceback, time

class Process(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._pconn, self._cconn = multiprocessing.Pipe()
        self._exception = None

    def run(self):
        try:
            multiprocessing.Process.run(self)
            self._cconn.send(None)
        except Exception as e:
            tb = traceback.format_exc()
            self._cconn.send((e, tb))
            #raise e  # You can still rise this exception if you need to

    @property
    def exception(self):
        if self._pconn.poll():
            self._exception = self._pconn.recv()
        return self._exception


# this function will be executed in a child process asynchronously
def failFunction():
   raise RuntimeError('trust fall, catch me!')

# execute the helloWorld() function in a child process in the background
process = Process(
 target = failFunction,
)
process.start()

# <this is where async stuff would happen>
time.sleep(1)

# catch the child process' exception
try:
    process.join()
    if process.exception:
        raise process.exception
except Exception as e:
    print( "Exception caught!" )
```

Example execution:

```
user@host:~$ python3 example.py 
Exception caught!
user@host:~$
```

Solution taken from this answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33599967/1174102

Answer (score 1):

**This solution does not require the target function having to catch its own exceptions.**

It may seem like overkill, but you can use class `ProcessPoolExecutor` in module `concurrent.futures` to create a process pool of size 1, which is all you that is required for your needs. When you submit a "job" to the executor a `Future` instance is created representing the state of execution of the process. When you call `result()` on the `Future` instance, you block until the process terminates and returns a results (the target function returns). If the target function throws an exception, you can catch it when you call `result()`:

```
import concurrent.futures

def failFunction():
   raise RuntimeError('trust fall, catch me!')

def main():
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        future = executor.submit(failFunction)
        try:
            result = future.result()
        except Exception as e:
            print('exception = ', e)
        else:
            print('result = ', result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Prints:

```
exception =  trust fall, catch me!
```

**The bonus of using a process pool is you have a ready-made process already created if you have additional functions you need to invoke in a sub-process.**

Comment: is there an equivalent of `Process.kill()` with a `ProcessPoolExecutor`?

Comment: Sadly, no. But you can take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782953/python-concurrent-futures-how-to-make-it-cancelable