# `concurrent.futures.Future.cancel()` Ineffectively Terminates Running threads and processes in context of `TimoutError`

Tags: python-3.x, concurrent.futures

In concurrent programming, managing thread states and interactions are crucial for both performance and correctness. Python's `concurrent.futures` framework provides a high-level utility for spawning and managing threads. We expect this utility to effectively control thread lifecycle, including starting, monitoring, and terminating threads.

The experiment below explores an issue with `concurrent.futures` where the `Future.cancel()` method appears to not effectively terminate a running subthread. Specifically, when we run a `Future` object with `Future.result(timeout=<duration>)` in context of an `Executor`, we expect the related thread to be canceled automatically upon timeout. However, this cancellation might not occur as expected, even if we explicitly invoke the `Future.cancel()` method in our `TimeoutError` handler.

## Question

How do we effectively time out long running tasks in python?

Note, we're not committed to either Processes or Threads. Answers to this question should include a working solution using `concurrent.futures`, `threading`, `multiprocessing`, or `asyncio`, or other standard libraries. A `concurrent.futures` solution is preferable.

## Details

My experiment spawns a single task which sleeps for 5 seconds. The main thread then waits for the result with a timeout of 3 seconds. If the task doesn't complete in time (which it shouldn't), the main thread will attempt to cancel the task. We expect the task to be interrupted and terminated at close to the 3 second mark. However, observations indicate this does not happen.

**Note: I performed the experiment with `ThreadPoolExecutor` and `ProcessPoolExecutor`. See below for both sets of results.**

Here is the Thread Pool version (other version is similar):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, TimeoutError
import math
import time

# Helpers
START_TIME = time.time()
def elapsed_seconds():
    # Round to nearest millisecond
    return round(time.time() - START_TIME, 3)

def log(mark, message):
    # Log execution with the following format:
    # > Mark text: Message Text (T+x.xxx seconds)
    print(f"{mark}: {message} (T+{elapsed_seconds()} seconds)")


# Experiment Setup
def sleep_experiment():
    log("Step 1", "Sleeping for 5 seconds ")
    time.sleep(5)
    log("Step 3", "Feeling rested! ")
    return "Refreshed!"

def run_experiment():
    # Create a thread executor
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        # Schedule experiment with executor
        experiment_future = executor.submit(sleep_experiment)
        try:
            # Run experiment with 3 second timeout
            result = experiment_future.result(timeout=3)

        # Handle timeout
        except TimeoutError:
            log("Step 2", "Timed out ")
            # Cancel experiment
            experiment_future.cancel()
            result = "Still tired! "

    log("Step 4", f"Outer Result: {result}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_experiment()
```

## Outcomes

### `ThreadPoolExecutor` outcome

```
Step 1: Sleeping for 5 seconds  (T+0.001 seconds)
Step 2: Timed out  (T+3.002 seconds)
Step 3: Feeling rested!  (T+5.006 seconds)
Step 4: Outer Result: Still tired!  (T+5.007 seconds)
```

We:

- Finish the experiment
- Reach step step 3 at ~t+5 seconds
- Reach step 4 at ~t+5 seconds

### `ProcessExecutor` outcome

```
Step 1: Sleeping for 5 seconds  (T+0.001 seconds)
Step 2: Timed out  (T+3.003 seconds)
Step 3: Feeling rested!  (T+5.004 seconds)
Step 4: Outer Result: Still tired!  (T+6.127 seconds)
```

We:

- Finish the experiment
- Reach step step 3 at ~t+5 seconds
- Reach step 4 at ~t+6 seconds

### Expected outcome

```
Step 1: Sleeping for 5 seconds  (T+0.001 seconds)
Step 2: Timed out  (T+3.002 seconds)
Step 4: Outer Result: Still tired!  (T+3.007 seconds)
```

We would:

- Cancel the experiment at 3 seconds
- Never reach step 3
- Reach step 4 in ~3 seconds

Comment: Threads cannot be cancelled. Even if they could, `result` does not cancel its task on timeout even if it could. The timeout is just the to stop waiting so that code is not blocked indefinitely. You may well wait for a result multiple times until it is finally ready.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to focus it on one thing? As far as I can tell there are currently *four* questions here: the "why isn’t the thread cancelled" situation outlined extensively plus the three explicit questions inbetween. Note that many of them are unanswerable: whether to choose async (which is single core) or processes (which do not share objects) or threads (which are bound by the GIL) depends on what you are actually doing. For a simple sleep, just letting the thread run or filtering its output with a flag would be enough.

Comment: Right.  Unless the process itself is terminating, a thread should always be in control of its own lifetime.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, please note the behavior happens with threads and processes. In both cases, even the `.cancel()` method fails.

If the experiment is an infinite loop, it will run forever:


```
def sleep_experiment():
    log("Step 1", "Running an infinite loop")
    while True:
        pass
    log("Step 3", "Finished Infinite loop ")
    return "Refreshed!"
```

Step 1: Running an infinite loop (T+0.001 seconds)
Step 2: Timed out  (T+3.003 seconds)

The computation hangs forever, regardless of whether we have used processes or threads.

Comment: @Tim-Roberts Please note that the question pertains to both processes and threads - both seem to be uncancellable. This should be surprising.

I would be much obliged if you can provide an example of how to run and then cancel a runaway task after a timeout. I am not committed to processes or threads. Feel free to use any standard library that will work. 

Thanks for your time.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have revised the question to specify that I'm after any working example. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: You can always kill a process.  A thread needs to be written so that it is checking a "should I die?" flag on a regular basis.  It needs to commit suicide, rather than being killed.

Comment: @TimRoberts That is the behavior I was expecting - the thread version should fail to cancel a runaway thread, but the process version should be able to cancel a runaway process. Unfortunately, when we run the ProcessExecutor version of the code, we still cannot cancel the future. See the ProcessExecutor outcome above. 

The process version gets stuck, and I can't see why. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: concurrent.futures How to make it cancelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42782953/python-concurrent-futures-how-to-make-it-cancelable)

Comment: Note a `Future` represents the *result* and not the *computation producing the result*. As such `Future.cancel` cancels only the future itself, not the underlying processing of it. It does not cancel *executing* futures; it only cancels futures that have not been considered for execution yet (and then won't execute).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi that answer does answer my question. To stop a process pool's subprocesses we can: 1) Shutdown the process pool using the executor's .shutdown method. 2) Kill all child subprocesses of the python process by using psutil to find them and send SIGTERM. This indicates that I might want to drop the ProcessPool abstraction and spawn my processes directly. Thank you very much for your help!